# ClickOnce manifest

Tags: .net-4.0, clickonce

We are currently deploying a WPF 4 application via [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) and there is a scenario when the installation fails.

If the user does not have .NET 4.0 Full install and attempts to install our application the framework installs fine, but the application fails to install. If we re-run the installation again the application installs fine.

Here is a copy of the log:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.4927
    System.Deployment.dll         : 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    mscorwks.dll             : 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    dfdll.dll             : 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    dfshim.dll             : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url            : [URL REMOVED]
                        Server        : Apache/2.0.54
    Application url            : [URL REMOVED]
                        Server        : Apache/2.0.54

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity        : Graphicly.App.application, Version=0.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c982228345371fbc, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : Graphicly.App.exe, Version=0.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c982228345371fbc, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Dependency Graphicly.WCFClient.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.WCFClient.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Design.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Design.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.Infrastructure.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Infrastructure.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.AutoUpdater.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.AutoUpdater.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency System.Windows.Interactivity.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file System.Windows.Interactivity.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.Fonts.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Fonts.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.Reader.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Reader.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.Controls.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Controls.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.SocialNetwork.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.SocialNetwork.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.Archive.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Archive.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency Graphicly.App.exe cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.App.exe: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Dependency GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll cannot be processed for patching. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    * Activation of [URL REMOVED] resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Cannot load internal manifest from component file.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The file named Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Newtonsoft.Json.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Dimebrain.TweetSharp.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named HtmlAgilityPack.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    * The file named Facebook.dll does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:33] : Activation of [URL REMOVED] has started.
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:38] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:38] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:39] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.WCFClient.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Design.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Infrastructure.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.AutoUpdater.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file System.Windows.Interactivity.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Fonts.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Reader.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Controls.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.SocialNetwork.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.Archive.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file Graphicly.App.exe: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.AddFilesInHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, AssemblyManifest applicationManifest, String applicationFolder)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:

    * [20/05/2010 09:17:41] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
        - Exception occurred loading manifest from file GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem item, Hashtable dependencyTable)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
        - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
        - Source:
        - Stack trace:


COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I'm baffled. What could this be?

I've noticed that dfsvc.exe that runs right after install is located in the .NET 2 folder. When I re-run the installer, the dfsvc.exe is located in the .NET 4 folder.

---

I've been speaking to Microsoft's support and we've found that due to the fact that a previous version of .NET 4 (beta in our case) was installed and un-installed it left several files behind. When the installer for .NET was executed, it required renaming some files then a reboot, but since the files were left by the previous version, the installer thought the renaming had already taken place and did not request a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all of the projects in your solution target .NET 4.0?
Is it .NET 4.0 Client Framework or the full shebang?
Are you deploying the right version of the framework in the prerequisites?

I'm going to send this one to the C/O product team and see if they have any input.

Comment: I've talked to the C/O product lead at Microsoft. He would like to know if the end user rebooted the machine after .NET 4.0 was installed? .NET 4.0 does require a reboot.

Comment: It's the full framework for all projects, the click once pre-reqs target it too. The machine didn't reboot but there was no option / warning to say it needed one.

Comment: I guess my question would be this: was the user prompted to reboot, and chose not to? Every machine I've installed .NET 4.0 on has requested a reboot. If this machine didn't, then that would indicate a problem with the installation of .NET 4.0. What OS is the machine running?

Comment: There was no prompt for the machines. The os's are Win 7 32 + 64

Comment: Ok, so the machines have .NET 3.5 installed on them, and C/O installs .NET 4.0 but it doesn't then prompt for a reboot. That's a problem. Would you like to file a bug in http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and post the link back here, and I'll share it with them? Sounds like a bug to me. If you don't want to post a bug, just comment back and I'll post it for you. (If YOU post it, they will respond to you and let you know when it's fixed.)

Comment: Yeah sure post the bug for me :) Thanks @RobinDotNet

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now claims this is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571570/clickonce-deployment-and-net-4-0-framework?wa=wsignin1.0), but that they do not have time to fix it in Visual Studio 2010, and that it will be "considered in future versions."

Answer (score 0):

A small percentage of our customers got this message in the logs when the application updated itself or was freshly installed, though it did not have to do with whether .NET 4 was already installed or not.

It turns out it was Panda Antivirus messing it up somehow.

By disabling it temporarily, the ClickOnce installation completed. This worked for us.