# ClickOnce fails with invalid manifest error via programmatic update but not framework update

Tags: clickonce, manifest, infragistics

We have been distributing a WPF application via ClickOnce for a couple of years. I am locally testing a forthcoming update which will upgrade it from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 (users have been warned in advance to upgrade their .NET version if they have not already).

We do the ClickOnce updates programmatically via a "Check for updates" menu item. I am finding that for this particular update, it downloads the update successfully through the API but when it tries to install I get this error relating to an Infragistics DLL:

"Exception occurred loading manifest from file InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.1.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened."

This causes the app to close there. When I then try to relaunch it from the shortcut, I get the ClickOnce framework's own "Update available" dialog because the app is still not up to date - and when I let it update, it successfully re-downloads, installs, and starts up fine. I have tested this whole process several times and it's consistent.

I don't know whether this has anything to do with Infragistics specifically, but as part of the update several Infragistics DLLs are being upgraded from WPF3 to WPF4.

Comment: Interesting... I have worked with ClickOnce before and I know that working with their licensing files and distributing their DLLs (which is legal, for the uninitiated) can sometimes be a headache.  My hunch is that the problem has to do with cached licensing codes and cached instances of the DLLs that are running in memory or are being checked against the current installed instance that is being upgraded.  Still, I'd have no idea how to fix this but if I had this problem, I'd be almost certain it was an issue with the Infragistics licensing system.

Comment: I suspect you are right, we have had issues with Infragistics licensing in the past. We have decided to ditch programmatic update checking and just use the framework's pre-startup check. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with loading the manifest from the assembly which doesn't have anything to do with the licensing logic for the controls.  Most likely the issue would happen with other assemblies as well if the .NET framework was changed for the assembly being updated.

I believe that this is likely the same issue that you have:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571570/clickonce-deployment-and-net-4-0-framework

The following question has some information that may help for looking into this:
[ClickOnce manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872567/clickonce-manifest-problem)